# State count and uf sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the employees, by state and UF, but when I run my code it counts by department:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATA_MART_CARGA 
AS 
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO') 
   BEGIN 
      CREATE TABLE DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO 
      (CD_MART INTIDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
       DEPTO VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
       ESTADO VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
       UF VARCHAR(2) NULL, 
       CONSTRAINT PK_DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO PRIMARY KEY(CD_MART)) 
   END 
ELSE 
   BEGIN 
     TRUNCATE TABLE DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO 
   END 
 
INSERT INTO DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO 
SELECT ESTADO,NM_ESTADO,UF 
FROM DWH  
 
EXECUTE SP_DATA_MART_CARGA 
 
SELECT * FROM DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO
 
CREATE VIEW FATO_CONTA 
AS 
SELECT DEPTO,COUNT(UF) AS 'CONTA' FROM DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO 
GROUP BY ESTADO
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Missing a few batch terminators? Please add sample data and expected outcome. Also the view syntax is wrong in that deptno is included in select but estado in group by - since you want by state change deptno to estado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view throws a syntax error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FATO_CONTA, Line 3
Invalid column name 'deptno'.

amend to

```
CREATE VIEW FATO_CONTA 
AS 
SELECT estado,COUNT(UF) AS 'CONTA' FROM DATA_MART_CONTA_ESTADO 
GROUP BY ESTADO
```